# How can I dynamically load two (or more) different versions of a class in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have multiple classes generated from xsd files (given to me by a third party), that conflict with each other, in terms of the class name and individual properties within the class.  I was thinking if I could load only one class at a time, I could use all these classes within one project.

Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

Comment: In my class the namespace is associated with a url.    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=true, [Namespace]:="http://atms.avanade.com/schemas/atms/Invoice.xsd"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="http://atms.avanade.com/schemas/atms/Invoice.xsd", IsNullable:=False)>

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

What you *can* do however is put them in different namespaces. Now you can have them all in your program *even at the same time*.

Comment: The class contains the following which includes a reference to the namespace

Comment: <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0"),
 System.SerializableAttribute(),
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://atms.avanade.com/schemas/atms/Invoice.xsd"),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="http://atms.avanade.com/schemas/atms/Invoice.xsd", IsNullable:=False) 
>

Comment: I did not mean the Xml namespace. That can stay. I meant the namespace of your class. If those classes are in different namespaces, you can load all of them at the same time, because they don't have the same (full) name any more.

Comment: If I try to add a namespace to my class file, the classes within it now give me an error "Transaction not defined", "Invoice not defined", etc.

Comment: You should add the Imports <Namespace> to the files that use your classes

Answer (score 0):

I found that xsd.exe also has a parameter /N for namespace - that inserts the namespace correctly - so I can follow that syntax for adding the namespace manually (or rerun xsd.exe)